# how to change screen orientation and get the changed canvas sizes

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on a unity UI project. I had multiple scenes. my scenes are on portrait mode except the last scene. last scene is landscape mode. 
for the last scene at start method I set Screen Orientation to LandscapeLeft and set the canvas scaler referance resolution 800*600. I work with 480*800 screen and screen match mode is "match width or height" and match is width so the canvas SHOULD scale up to 800*480 on landscape mode. because of the width must match the height is gonna be the max value for screen

but when I run unity the screen doesnt change to landscape for last scene and the canvas sizes are 800*1333 when I select the landscape resolution 800*480 the canvas sizes change to 800*480 but since the script cant wait for me to select the resolution my script thinks the canvas sizes are 800*480

```
void Start()
{
   Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft;
   Debug.Log(Screen.width+" - "+Screen.height);//output: 480-800
   Debug.Log(canvas.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.width + " - " + canvas.GetComponent<RectTransform>().rect.height);//output: 800-1333
}
```

[image]

I set to landscape at start but game comes like this I expected to change to this:

[image]

am I doing wrong when I try to change the orientation ? why doesnt the game panel change to landscape
How can I get the landscape canvas sizes?

Comment: Post pictures and code

Comment: @vasmos editted.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the orientation of your device does not rotate or scale canvases.

The match width or height will just scale the canvas until it hits a side of the screen or the top/bottom of the screen if its played using a device not matching the original resolution.

Solution:

Change canvas to world space and rotate/scale it when you change the device orientation

Edit:

In your canvas component under 'Render Mode' select world space

Comment: I am recording the screen if I rotate I got a rotated video
how can I change canvas to screen space??

Comment: sorry I meant world space

Comment: in click your canvas component, then select world space under 'render mode'

Comment: I cant the recorder module (natcorder) requires camera

Comment: in a game with 480*800 portrait selected; is `Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft;` and selecting the 800*480 LandScape from the game window same thing ? if so why the game doesnt change

Comment: I think in screen space the canvas is scaled once when the app starts but not again when orientation is changed

Comment: I dont have any problem with scale

Comment: my problem is in a game where canvas scaler referance resolution is set to 800*480;
 if the game window is set to 480*800 portrait the canvas sizes are 800*1333 and if I set it to 800*480 landscape the canvas sizes are 800*480 
I can scale the necessary object but for that referance I need the sizes of canvas and when I set the orientation to landscapethe canvas sizes I get is the same as the 480*800 portrait selected in game window but I need the landscape sizes

Comment: I want to change the game window like my second picture when I set `Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft;`

Comment: Yeah I think the only way to do that is to have canvas as world space and rotate/scale it, because before this your game is in portrait right? When you change your screen orientation your canvas doesn't rotate into landscape